# Const correctness advice

Tags: c++, constants

I have a function that receives a const reference and I need to call a template library function using this reference:

```
std::vector<cv::Size> get_resolutions(const rs2::device& dev)
{
    auto sensor = dev.first<rs2::depth_sensor>();

    //more code    
}


class device
{
public:

    template<class T>
    T first()
    {
        for (auto&& s : query_sensors())
        {
            if (auto t = s.as<T>()) return t;
        }
        throw rs2::error("Could not find requested sensor type!");
    }

    //more code

};
```

When I compile with gcc I get this error:

*error: passing 'const rs2::device' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]*

I can't change the first() function as it's part of a external library (librealsense, line 51 in [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/include/librealsense2/hpp/rs_device.hpp)).
I can't remove the const from the function argument dev because that will result in removing const correctness in a lot of places.

I can overcome the error by removing the const from dev:

```
auto sensor = const_cast<rs2::device&>(dev).first<rs2::depth_sensor>();
```

However, this feels bad practice. Is there any more correct way of dealing with this error? I have tried unsuccessfully the following variations:

```
auto sensor = dev.first<const rs2::depth_sensor>();
auto sensor = const_cast<const rs2::depth_sensor>(dev.first<rs2::depth_sensor>());
```

but I get the same error with them.

Comment: Put this `rs2::device` object in a `std::shared_ptr` (or maybe unique_ptr) store it inside a wrapper object, and have your wrapper object be a facade for it. Specify the const-ness of your facade's methods, that get forwarded to `rs2::device` methods. Your facade's `template<class T> T first() const` will have no issues dereferencing the wrapped `const` std::shared_ptr, and then calling the real method in the wrapped object.

Comment: The best thing to do is remove what you think is the const correctness - because it's a library function; and for all you know `first` DOES change the object.  The whole point of const correctness is that it has to be ... correct ;)

Comment: You may ask the developers what the intent actually is. It is very likely that the `const` is just missing there, as the only other potentially modifying operation there is a call `query_sensors` which is however `const` itself. If that should be the case, go ahead and use `const_cast` right away, as in future this might get adapted, but you are certain that this cast will never lead to UB. If however this was the intent, do as @UKMonkey said or split up the function into a `const` and a `mutable` part.

Comment: It seems to me that the lib function should be `const`. You could fork it and add the `const`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two possible solutions to this. Either you allow `get_resolutions` to take `dev` by non-const reference (although that may require you to modify code at the call site), or you re-implement `first` yourself.

#### Option 1

Just replace

```
std::vector<cv::Size> get_resolutions(const rs2::device& dev)
```

with

```
std::vector<cv::Size> get_resolutions(rs2::device& dev)
```

This, however, would also mean that you can no longer call `get_resolutions` with a temporary object.

#### Option 2

Looking at the [source of the library](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/include/librealsense2/hpp/rs_device.hpp), however, I really can't see why `first()` is non-const. All it does is call `query_sensors()` (which *is* const-qualified, and also public), and process the results:<sup>1</sup>

```
template<class T>
T first()
{
    for (auto&& s : query_sensors())
    {
        if (auto t = s.as<T>()) return t;
    }
    throw rs2::error("Could not find requested sensor type!");
}
```

This might be the option with the lowest impact: Just define a `first()` yourself, outside of the library, that replicates this functionality:

```
template <class T>
T custom_first(const rs2::device& dev)
{
    for (auto&& s : dev.query_sensors())
        if (auto t = s.as<T>())
            return t;
    throw rs2::error("Could not find requested sensor type!");
}
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Time to file a bug report, maybe?</sup>

Comment: I'll open an issue in the librealsense project. and temporarily use the custom_first()